# How to set sizes of synthetic_data dataframes for sdv multi_table (HMASynthesizer)?

Tags: python, sdv

I've simple (or not) question.
How I can set num_rows for synthetic_data generated by HMASynthesizer?
Tables:

|  | region_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | r_0 | Cohenville |
| 1 | r_1 | Lake Martha |
| 2 | r_2 | West Josephfurt |
| 3 | r_3 | East Valerieshire |
| 4 | r_4 | Madisonport |

|  | user_id | names | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Tammy | r_2 |
| 1 | 1 | Edward | r_1 |
| 2 | 2 | Veronica | r_3 |
| 3 | 3 | Kelly | r_1 |
| 4 | 4 | Jennifer | r_0 |

```
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker
from sdv.metadata import MultiTableMetadata
from sdv.multi_table import HMASynthesizer

fake = Faker('en_US)

multi_table_data = {
    'users': df,
    'regions': regions
}

metadata = MultiTableMetadata()

metadata.detect_table_from_dataframe(
    table_name='users',
    data=df
)

metadata.update_column(
    table_name='users',
    column_name='user_id',
    sdtype='id',
    regex_format='[0-9]{1}')


metadata.update_column(
    table_name='users',
    column_name='region_id',
    sdtype='id',
    regex_format='[A-Za-z]{3}')

metadata.update_column(
    table_name='users',
    column_name='names',
    sdtype='first_name',
)

metadata.set_primary_key(
    table_name='users',
    column_name='user_id'
)

metadata.detect_table_from_dataframe(
    table_name='regions',
    data=regions
)

metadata.update_column(
    table_name='regions',
    column_name='region_id',
    sdtype='id',
    regex_format='r_[0-9]{1}',
)

metadata.update_column(
    table_name='regions',
    column_name='address',
    sdtype='address',
)

metadata.set_primary_key(
    table_name='regions',
    column_name='region_id'
)

metadata.add_relationship(
    parent_table_name='regions',
    child_table_name='users',
    parent_primary_key='region_id',
    child_foreign_key='region_id'
)

synthesizer = HMASynthesizer(metadata, locales=['en_US'])
synthesizer.fit(multi_table_data)

synthetic_data = synthesizer.sample()
```

Synthetic data (I can't control size of dataframes):

|  | user_id | names | region_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Jennifer | r_0 |
| 1 | 1 | David | r_1 |
| 2 | 2 | Thomas | r_1 |
| 3 | 3 | Claudia | r_2 |
| 4 | 4 | Bruce | r_3 |
| 5 | 5 | Lisa | r_3 |
| 6 | 6 | Andrew | r_4 |

|  | region_id | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | r_0 | 77809 Rush Mountain Suite 952 Garciaton, DC 32497 |
| 1 | r_1 | USS Morrow FPO AP 28106 |
| 2 | r_2 | 123 Dennis Points Humphreymouth, IN 32470 |
| 3 | r_3 | Unit 2560 Box 7577 DPO AA 88965 |
| 4 | r_4 | 46038 Karen Via Apt. 979 Arnoldmouth, PA 22955 |

Answer (score 0):

Size of synthetic data can be set by scale:
synthetic_data = synthesizer.sample(scale=0.2)